# how to visible nested layout when click root layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

I am developing an android application in that i have a linear layout that contains one root layout(invitation_single)and two nested layouts namely(hidden,hidden1).In "hidden1" layout i have two textviews and "hidden" layout contains three buttons(yes,no,maybe),now my need is when click root layout i am need to visible two nested layouts at same time,after visible sub layout when i am click anyone of these buttons(yes,no,maybe) the nested layout hide and again to visble root layout.
             here is my layout code,

```
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_event" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/invitation_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="0dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/invitation_place"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="0dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/hidden1"
                    android:layout_width="1000dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/place"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/hidden"
                    android:layout_width="310dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="1dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:weightSum="3">


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/yesbutton"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/blue"
                        android:text="Yes"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/nobutton"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/blue"
                        android:text="No"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonmaybe"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/blue"
                        android:text="Maybe"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
```

In below code, layout first is root layout and layout second & third is nested layouts,in coding i am try to visible the nested layouts when on click the root layout but nested layout "hidden" is only visible,but i am need to visible both sub layouts at the same time when i am click layout hidden the nested layouts are need to gone and show root layout.how can i achieve this...

```
final LinearLayout first = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);
     final LinearLayout second = 
     (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden);
     final LinearLayout third = 
     (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden1);
                         first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            third.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                        }

                                    });
```

Comment: Third layout might be in visible state, the problem is that view is not adjusted in your screen. Check it is that third layout adjusted or not your screen by giving visibility state to VISIBLE instead of GONE in your xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way,

```
final LinearLayout rootLayout= (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);

rootLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
```

//And then add onClickListener method and do what you want.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 //do what you want to do when button is clicked
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.invitation_single:
           // Do your staff
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: can u pls verify the code that i am tried,switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.invitation_single:
                            second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            third.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;

Comment: when using that code i saw a textview layout(hidden) only and the "hidden1" layout still not visible.

Comment: @selvasimonp yes.got the point .For avoid this,please create parent layout & set this two layout as a child layout.i hope it helps you

Comment: just edited my answer,try this way,if not working then try

Comment: yeah now the problem resolved..thanks for your response.

Comment: @selvasimonp Great to hear .which logic you used? Upvote my answer if you think my logic true.happy coding

Comment: i am used that parent layout concept and remove hidden1 layout because parent layout already have textviews so i am just use parent layout and one nested layout.when click parent layout that layout also visible..i am just  additionaly visible the nested layout immediately below main layout thus the way the problem could solved.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to set visiblity gone in your both child layout..

```
  final LinearLayout rootLayout= (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);

    final LinearLayout ChildLayout1= (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ChildLayout1);

    final LinearLayout ChildLayout2= (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ChildLayout2);

     rootLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   //set visibility for  your child layout
                    ChildLayout1.setVisibility(View.Visible);
                    ChildLayout2.setVisibility(View.Visible);
                    }
            });
```